# filter array values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an arrays of values that contain the title names of different applications.

Example:

```
$scope.badge = [{title: 'Incidents'},{title: 'News'}]
```

In the main page, where I place all the different apps, I would like to get the name for the specific app.

How can I filter the values so I can get the correct title for each app?

Something like this:

```
<span>{{badge.title}}</span>
```

**UPDATE/ SOLUTION**

I got it to work. The solution is below:

```
$scope.badges = {           
                     titles: [
                                 {id: 2, name: 'Incidents'},
                                 {id: 3, name: 'News'}
                             ]
                 };

<div ng-repeat="title in badges.titles | filter:{id:2}">    
    <ul>
        <li>                                                                
            <a class="{{title.name}}" ng-click="addNew()">Add New {{title.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

For my current purposes, that did it for me. If there is a more elegant, dynamic solution, I would like to learn it.

Many thanks to all.

Comment: what do you mean by correct?

Comment: loop through the $scope.badge using ng-repeat .

Comment: yup, what's the criteria on which you want to filter out the correct application name ?

Comment: I meant the appropriate name for each app. Get the label incident for the app that loads the incidents, get the label news for the app that displays the news.

Comment: can you show me how it is done?

Comment: Use different keys for each app then instead of just label

Comment: I posted the code I attempted but did not work. Can you see if you can identify what I am missing?

Comment: why are you filtering for `id` when that property doesn't exist in data shown? If it does then show proper data

Comment: I see that, I replace id with key instead

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem. Also remove the filter part to see if ng-repeat is even working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browsers you're using support [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you can do something like this.

```
$scope.badge = [{label: 'Incidents', appName: 'incident'},{label: 'News', appName: 'news'}];

//I'm not positive how to get the app name, but APP_NAME can be replaced with that
<span>{{badge.find(function(option) { return option.appName == APP_NAME})}}</span>
```